# nfc between 2 raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfc

I'm doing a project that will involve multiple raspberry pi with NFC shields. Has there ever been a project that made 2 raspberry pi communicate between them using NFC ? In the end, I want to be able to transfer some JSON data from one raspberry to another one through NFC.
Thank you !

Comment: Couldn't you use the built-in bluetooth more simply/cheaply?

Comment: I can't, my project will already be using Bluetooth for something else (A2DP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NFC Forum defined a mode for symmetrical communication between two devices sporting an NFC frontend, the mode is called peer-to-peer and employed with the Logical Link Control Protocol LLCP. This provides both connection-less and connection-oriented exchange schemes between application endpoints. There are a few LLCP implementations around like https://github.com/nfc-tools/libllcp (C/C++) or https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy (Python).